# file name to access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am a novice and your help and patience will be greatly appreciated. Many tks in advance. I need the correct syntax/code to get a file name into an access dbase table. Below is the code and output. Output is 8 colums, first 7 columns are numbers and column 8 is where I want the file name.   The code goes to  a directory, checks for all the csv files there then imports the csv data into an access dbase table.I need to populate column 'com' with the csv filename. At the moment it is populated with a string.

```
Sub Import_multiple_csv_files()


Const strPath As String = "C:\text1\" 'Directory Path
Dim strFile As String 'Filename
Dim strFileList() As String 'File  Array
Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number
Dim SQL As String

 'Loop through the folder & build file list
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
While strFile <> ""
     'add files to the list
    intFile = intFile + 1
    ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
    strFileList(intFile) = strFile
    strFile = Dir()
Wend
 'see if any files were found
If intFile = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If
 'cycle through the list of files &  import to Access
 'creating a new table called MyTable
     SQL = " UPDATE Test SET Com = ""'strFile'"" WHERE Com IS NULL OR Com=''"
For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelimi, , _
    "Test", strPath & strFileList(intFile)
   'DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
   CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```

Output seems not to

```
F1          F2      F3      F4      F5      F6      F7      com
20111128    2.6922  2.6922  2.6922  2.6922  3340    17696   'strFile'
20111129    2.7229  2.7229  2.7229  2.7229  5010    18141   'strFile'
20111130    2.7401  2.7401  2.7401  2.7401  3641    18723   'strFile'
20111201    2.7376  2.7376  2.7376  2.7376  8087    19321   'strFile'
20111202    2.7784  2.7784  2.7784  2.7784  0       0       'strFile'
20111128    2.6727  2.6727  2.6727  2.6727  3889    26111   'strFile'
20111129    2.7039  2.7039  2.7039  2.7039  4562    26647   'strFile'
20111130    2.722   2.722   2.722   2.722   3043    27099   'strFile'
20111201    2.7218  2.7218  2.7218  2.7218  9180    27037   'strFile'
20111202    2.7623  2.7623  2.7623  2.7623  0       0       'strFile'
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off editing your original question than raising a new one but the answer is that you are confusing your quotes and not concatenating the variable into the string, Should be something like:

```
SQL = "UPDATE Test SET Com = '''" & strFile & "''' WHERE Com IS NULL OR Com = ''"
```

Surrounding your strFile with quotes is causing it to be treated as as string literal rather than getting the value of the string variable itself.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your feedback. I tried the script above but now the output in column com is 2 quote marks  '' ? What am I doing wrong?  Many thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it's one single quote on each side. It's been a while since I did any VBA and I don't have Access installed on my current computer to test.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't actually want single quotes in the data:

```
SQL = "UPDATE Test SET Com = '" & strFile & "' WHERE LEN(Com) = 0;"
```

...but I think you need to change the SQL inside your later loop e.g.

```
'cycle through the list of files &  import to Access
'creating a new table called MyTable

SQL = "UPDATE Test SET Com = '{0}' WHERE LEN(Com) = 0;"

For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)

  DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelimi, , _
      "Test", strPath & strFileList(intFile)
  CurrentDb.Execute Replace$(SQL, "{0}", strPath & strFileList(intFile))
```

...but that would only take effect once when the null and blank values are updated!

Comment: Hi, I dont want any quotes in the data just the filename. Unfortunately these 2 options also only put quotes in to the access table cells in column 8 and no file name. Could it be that at the time the script puts the &strFile& into the cell, this string is actually empty? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @SidVicious: I've updated my answer. In answer to your comment: yes, because of your earlier loop, `While strFile <> ""` i.e. when that exits `strFile = ""` is true.

Comment: @simon  Hi, Great News, Brilliant results, the strFileList(intFile) is the correct string and this is now loaded into the column 'com'. Many thanks. Only one small problem. At the moment I load 2 files. However, the same file name, file name 2 (the last file in the folder) is loaded throughout the column instead of the file name 1  with data from file 1 and file name 2 with data from file 2 . It seems the load to the column is not taking place after the strFileList(intFile) changes. Any suggestions on how to remedy this?? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Why is the same file name loaded into column com? How do I get the script to load the file name from where the data came?

Comment: @SidVicious: Because the first time it gets execute it replaces all the blank/null values with the first file name, after that there are blank/null values to update any more. You need to extend you `WHERE` clause to account for each file name iteration and I cannot even guess at what that might be.